# Can I use WolframScript to solve this system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, scripting

I have these three equations:

```
f = a*b*(a + b - 4*x - 2*y - z) + x*(x + y)*(2*x + y + z);
g = (a*b*((a + b)*(a + b - 4*x - 2*y - z)^2 + x*(x + y)*(2*x + y + z) - 12*c*d*(a + b - c - d - 4*x - 2*y - z)) - x*(x + y)*(2*x + y + z)*(5*x*(x + y) + 2*x*z + y^2 + y*z))/12;
h = 2*(c + d) + 4*x + 2*y + z
```

I want to get values for `x`, `y`, and `z` in terms of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `dMax` under the following circumstances:

- the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `dMax` stand for arbitrary positive real numbers
- `x`, `y`, and `z` are positive real numbers
- `f == 0`
- `g == dMax`
- `h` is minimized (a positive real number as close to zero as possible)

**How would I input this in Wolfram Language?** The documentation for `Minimize[]` seems to say that it only works on one function at a time, and `Solve[]` doesn't seem to handle minimization unless I'm missing something.

**EDIT**

Based on @Michael E2's comments and @Ulrich Neumann's answer I tried entering the following:

```
$PrePrint = InputForm;
f = a*b*(a + b - 4*x - 2*y - z) + x*(x + y)*(2*x + y + z);
g = (a*b*((a + b)*(a + b - 4*x - 2*y - z)^2 + x*(x + y)*(2*x + y + z) - 12*c*d*(a + b - c - d - 4*x - 2*y - z)) - x*(x + y)*(2*x + y + z)*(5*x*(x + y) + 2*x*z + y^2 + y*z))/12;
h = 2*(c + d) + 4*x + 2*y + z;
mini[a_, b_, c_, d_, dMax_] := Minimize[{h, {f == 0, g == dMax, a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0}}, {x, y, z}];
mini[a, b, c, d, dMax]
```

The program sits at around 70-90% CPU usage for hours without resolving. Is there a better way to do this? Or is there anything obvious I can do to the input equations to make the computation more efficient?

Comment: General tip (does not solve problem): [Avoid capitals](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395), esp. ones like `C` and `D` which are  `Protected` system symbols.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Besides being against best-practice, would using `C` and `D` cause any problems in this specific case?

Comment: It might, though it's unlikely. Sometimes internal functions use `Quiet[]` to suppress error messages, so just because there were no errors does not rule out a problem. That there are no errors is substantial evidence that `C` and `D` are not the issue, but you can't be completely certain. For instance, if Mma tries to assign `C` or `D` a value, then there would probably be a problem (try out `Block[{D = 4}, D[x^2, x]]`, and no error message). I tried Ulrich's code or one similar (he didn't distinguish `D`/`d`) and it did not finish in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I updated my functions to use lowercase letters and renamed the old `d` to `dMax`, as it seems like multi-character variable names are allowed. Are there any other best-practices I should be aware of?

Comment: Probably not. Though using `=` for variable assignments such as `f = x^2` and `:=` for function assignments such as `f[x_] := x^3;` is common. (So the '=' you had originally is fine.) The [list I linked earlier](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) has grown to have excessively many pieces of advice. But it was originally meant to be a first resource for new users. The 2nd & 3rd groups are mostly important; if you use numerical methods, the `NumericQ` one is important.

Comment: For your problem above, realize that as the number of parameters and variables grow in a nonlinear problem, the complexity can grow quite fast. Mma will generally analyze the parameters, because it tries to prove to itself that it has found a minimum. After it has found all the critical points. In theory, being a problem involving polynomials with polynomial coefficients, it can be solved. But it might take and excessive amount of time. (My CPU ran at nearly 800% for maybe 20 min. before I killed it.) If you can simplify your problem at all, it might help significantly.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Unfortunately this is as simple as I've been able to make it so far... the `g` function started out over 2700 characters long before extensive work in cancelling and noticing that a subset of its terms contained a factor of the `f` function (which will be set to zero) and could thus be cut out. I'll keep working on it though.

Comment: @Lawton Still you didn't modify the definitions  `f:=...,g:=...,h:=...` to `f=...,g=...,h=..` as proposed by MichaelE2

Answer (score 0):

**modified**

Perhaps

```
(N)Minimize[{h,{f==0,g==d,a>0,b>0,c>0,d>0}},{a,b,c,d}]
```

**QP  changed content of the question. Now he's looking for optimal {x,y,z}**:

```
mini[a_, b_, c_, d_, dMax_] := Block[{
J = 2*(c + d) + 4*x + 2*y + z,
zwang = {a*b*(a + b - 4*x - 2*y - z) + x*(x + y)*(2*x + y + z) == 0,
(a*b*((a + b)*(a + b - 4*x - 2*y - z)^2 + x*(x + y)*(2*x + y + z)-12*c*d*(a + b - c - d - 4*x - 2*y - z)) - x*(x + y)*(2*x + y +z)*(5*x*(x + y) + 2*x*z + y^2 + y*z))/12 == dMax}},
  
NMinimize[{J, zwang}, {x, y, z}]]
```

example

```
mini[1, 1, 1, 1, .1]
(*{4.1, {x -> 1., y -> -2.9, z -> 1.9}}*)
```

Comment: I tried `NMinimize[{h, {f == 0, g == d, A > 0, B > 0, C > 0, D > 0}}, {A, B, C, D}]` and the program ran for about half an hour at around 40% CPU usage and using steadily increasing amounts of RAM until it reached 63.8 out of 64 GB, then another ten minutes or so at 100% hard-disk utilization, before crashing with an error that there was no more memory available. I then tried `Minimize[{h, {f == 0, g == d, A > 0, B > 0, C > 0, D > 0}}, {A, B, C, D}]`, and it's been running at between 70% and 90% CPU utilization for five hours with no sign of progress. Is this expected or is something wrong?

Comment: `Block[{x = 1, y = 1, z = 1}, 
 NMinimize[{h, {f == 0, g == d, a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0}}, {a, b, 
   c, d}]
 
 ]` evaluates in .5 seconds!

Comment: I think I didn't convey everything to you fully. `D` and `d` were separate variables. I've updated my question to not use single-uppercase-character variable names per Michael E2, so now the function `g` should now be equal to `dMax`. I also want to solve for `x`, `y`, and `z` in terms of the other named variables; setting `x`, `y`, and `z` to a specific value seems counterproductive. I'm now trying `Minimize[{h, {f == 0, g == dMax, a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0}}, {x, y, z}]`; I'll update with how it goes.

Comment: @Lawton You changed the question without notification. Now you're looking for optimal x,y,z!!!

Comment: I did not change the content of my question with regards to what variables I wanted to solve for. You can look at the edit history yourself to confirm that.

Comment: Using your new suggestion, I get the error `NMinimize::bcons: The following constraints are not valid: {a b (a + b - 4 x - 2 y - z) + x (x + y) (2 x + y + z) == 0, (-(x (x + y) (2 x + y + z) (y^2 + 5 x (x + y) + 2 x z + y z)) + a b ((a + b) (a + b - 4 x - 2 y - z)^2 - 12 c d (a + b - c - d - 4 x - 2 y - z) + x (x + y) (2 x + y + z)))/12 == (dMax_)}. Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables.`

Comment: At the end there it looks like you have `dMax_` (with an underscore).  Try removing that (not from the left-hand side of `mini[... dMax_] = `, it's needed there; but from the right-hand-side of that statement).

Comment: @evanb You're right, I had forgotten to remove that underscore. After fixing that I no longer get an error, but I left the program running for 12 hours and it didn't return any result.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I'd like to get symbolic expressions for `x`, `y`, and `z` in terms of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `dMax` *as variables*, rather than getting specific numeric values for `x`, `y`, and `z` for specific numeric values of  `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `dMax`.

Comment: Do you have reason to expect a symbolic expression for the global minimum exists?